OpenLayers 5 sends negative values for TileCol and TileRow parameters in WMTS GetTile request to server
In the WMTS server GetCapabilities I have only one layer with a TileMatrixSet like below. The layer is a geoTiff file with grid size: 2048 x 1024 and geo resolution in CRS EPGS:4326 is 0.17578125:
 <Layer>
            <ows:Title>test_wmts_worldmap</ows:Title>
            <ows:Abstract/>
            <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
                <ows:LowerCorner>-180 -90</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>180 90</ows:UpperCorner>
            </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
            <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326">
                <ows:LowerCorner>-90 -180</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>90 180</ows:UpperCorner>
            </ows:BoundingBox>
            <ows:Identifier>test_wmts_worldmap</ows:Identifier>
            <Style>
                <ows:Identifier>default</ows:Identifier>
            </Style>
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
            <TileMatrixSetLink>
                <TileMatrixSet>test_wmts_worldmap--EPSG--4326</TileMatrixSet>
            </TileMatrixSetLink>
        </Layer>
        <TileMatrixSet>
            <ows:Identifier>test_wmts_worldmap--EPSG--4326</ows:Identifier>
            <ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::test_wmts_worldmap--EPSG--4326</ows:SupportedCRS>
            <TileMatrix>
                <ows:Identifier>test_wmts_worldmap</ows:Identifier>
                <!-- 1 pixel = 0.17578125 degree -->
                <ScaleDenominator>0.17578125</ScaleDenominator>
                <TopLeftCorner>90 -180</TopLeftCorner>
                <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
                <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
                <MatrixWidth>8</MatrixWidth>
                <MatrixHeight>4</MatrixHeight>
            </TileMatrix>
        </TileMatrixSet>

then in the OpenLayers 5 client, I have this code:
<html>

<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>

</body>


<script>
const wmtsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.WMTS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/server/ows',
    layer: 'test_wmts_worldmap', // Matches WMTS layer name
    matrixSet: 'test_wmts_worldmap--EPSG--4326', // Matches TileMatrixSet identifier
    format: 'image/png',
    projection: 'EPSG:4326', // WMTS service's CRS
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
      origin: [90, -180], // TopLeftCorner from TileMatrixSet
      resolutions: [
        0.17578125, // 1 pixel resolution for test_wmts_worldmap
      ],
      matrixIds: [
        'test_wmts_worldmap',
      ],
      tileSize: [256, 256], // Tile dimensions
      extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90], // Full extent of EPSG:4326
    }),
    style: 'default', // Matches WMTS style
  }),
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
    wmtsLayer, // Add WMTS layer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [15, 50], // Center in EPSG:4326
    zoom: 2, // Adjust zoom to match TileMatrix levels
  }),
});
</script>


</html>


then, I got invalid request from OpenLayers 5 with negative values for TileCol and TileRow
http://localhost:8080/server/ows?layer=test_wmts_worldmap&style=default&tilematrixset=test_wmts_worldmap--EPSG--4326&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=image%2Fpng&TileMatrix=test_wmts_worldmap
&TileCol=-6&TileRow=-3

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

I would suspect that you are asking for a tile that is outside the grid

@IanTurton certainly, but this is OpenLayers doing that, I didn't do the request.

did you ask for a map that was bigger than the area of tiles available?

Your origin is 90 degrees south of the south pole

@IanTurton no, I only zoom in inside the map (i.e. the map covers world map), I zoom in America for example.

@Mike I think you replied me to OpenLayers Github as well. I tried to swap to [-180,90] but it seems doesn't help.
  origin: [-180, 90], // TopLeftCorner from TileMatrixSet


So you still get negative values for rows and columns with origin: [-180, 90]?

@Mike Your suggestion is correct, I retested it with Lon, Lat as origin and it works fine.

@TomazicM It works, I was wrong  (too busy to test properly).

Your origin has swapped coordinates, it should be origin: [-180, 90]. But since you define grid extent, origin is not necessary, this would be enough:
tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
  resolutions: [
    0.17578125, // 1 pixel resolution for test_wmts_worldmap
  ],
  matrixIds: [
    'test_wmts_worldmap',
  ],
  tileSize: [256, 256], // Tile dimensions
  extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90], // Full extent of EPSG:4326
})

If after layer creation you then retrieve layer grid origin with wmtsLayer.getSource().getTileGrid().getOrigin(), you will get [-180, 90].

thank you for that, it works with origin: [-180, 90] and without this origin.
